# Smooth image pasting with Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to paste a png image on another png image.

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

path = 'image.png'
image = Image.open(path).convert("RGBA").resize((80,80))


back = Image.open('base.png').convert("RGBA")

back.paste(image.convert("RGB"), (80,80), image)
back.save('result.png')
```

With that I'm getting:

[image: Bad Result]

However, I would like something like:

[image: Good Result]

With a smoother transition between image and background

Comment: In order to make a proper [mcve] maybe you could post your two input images separately so that folks have something to work with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha channel of the bear is what determines what you can see at each location and therefore it controls the transition. If there is a step-change in the bear's alpha, there'll be a step-change in the transition.

So, you need to extract the alpha channel from the bear, soften it or smooth it with some type of blur and then put it back in the bear image and paste on top of the background as before.

```
# Split image into channels
R, G, B, A = bear.split()

# Blur/soften/smooth A channel
softA = ...
...

# Recombine channels
softBear = Image.merge('RGBA', (R, G, B, softA))
```